# AWS Amplify - "List apps call failed / Network Failure"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zy2Um.png)I'm running into this issue in AWS Amplify. It's quite straight to the point, not much to explain.

I can't create a new App. I'm receiving the "List of apps call failed / Network Failure".

Anyone faced this issue before? If so, how can I fix it?

Lmk please.

There's nothing to try, just to be able to create an App.